# How to add item divider for RecyclerView in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm working on an app where I have a list with recyclerview and I want to add a divider for items. I have created the ItemDividerDecorator class and xml layout file but I'm not connecting to recycler view.

I know how to do in java, something like this:

```
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(
                new DividerItemDecoration(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.drawable.item_separator)));
```

but how can I do in Kotlin, I also tried to convert it in Android Studio but shows me a couples of errors. Here is my Decorator class:

```
    private val mdivider:Drawable
    init{
        this.mdivider = mdivider
    }
    override fun onDrawOver(canvas: Canvas, parent:RecyclerView, state:RecyclerView.State) {
        val left = parent.getPaddingLeft()
        val right = parent.getWidth() - parent.getPaddingRight()
        val childCount = parent.getChildCount()
        for (i in 0 until childCount)
        {
            val child = parent.getChildAt(i)
            val params = child.getLayoutParams() as RecyclerView.LayoutParams
            val top = child.getBottom() + params.bottomMargin
            val bottom = top + mdivider.getIntrinsicHeight()
            mdivider.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom)
            mdivider.draw(canvas)
        }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For Kotlin:

```
 recycler_view.addItemDecoration(
            DividerItemDecoration(
                context,
                LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL
            )
        )
```

If you intialized like this:

```
private lateint var context:Context
```

then inside your onCreateView

```
 override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Intialize context here 
    context = parent.context()
    rootView = container?.inflateView(layoutToInflate) ?: View(context)
    onFragmentCreated(rootView)
    return rootView
}
```

If you're using inside an activity then instead use

> applicationContext

```
val decorator = DividerItemDecoration(applicationContext, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL)
            decorator.setDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(applicationContext, R.drawable.file)!!)
            recycler_view.addItemDecoration(decorator)
```

Comment: I'm having this error with context:   kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property context has not been initialized

Comment: Did you intialized context like this? private lateint var context:Context

Intialize context first, In your on create method,

context = parent.context()

Comment: yes I did as private lateinit var context:Context, but still the error

Comment: The error states that you didn't intialized the lateint property, please find my edited answer for solution.

Comment: then use `DividerItemDecoration(applicationContext,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL)`

Comment: Its not showing divider, I also need to call the drawable file

Comment: Use setDrawable() method

`DividerItemDecoration(applicationContext,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL).setDrawable(**YOUR DRAWABLE FILE**)`

Comment: I did but its not working, Type: mismatch, Required: RecyclerView.ItemDecoration, Found: Unit

Comment: You need to do like this

`val decorator = DividerItemDecoration(applicationContext,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL)`

and after that

`decorator.setDrawable(**YOUR DRAWABLE FILE**)`

`recycler_view.addItemDecoration(decorator)`

Comment: I did but now I'm having an error with drawable, Type: mismatch, Required: Drawable, Found: Int

Comment: Edited, please see the above answer

Comment: If i do first method it will clickable ?

Comment: I mean recyler view will clickable or not

Answer (score 16):

Try this for `Kotlin`

for default item separator

```kotlin
recyclerview.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(this@YourActivity, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL))
```

drawable as a item separator

```kotlin
val divider = DividerItemDecoration(this@MainActivity,DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL)
divider.setDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this@MainActivity,R.drawable.item_separator)!!)
recyclerview.addItemDecoration(divider)
```

for `Java`

```java
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getContext(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
```

Comment: I tried this, shows an error with this: Type mismatch, Required: Context, Found:

Comment: But how can I add the drawable file

Comment: check now you can use item separator from drawable

Comment: I found solution see Mohan answer

Answer (score 0):

Add material divider as

```
val itemDecorator = MaterialDividerItemDecoration(requireContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL).apply {
        dividerInsetEnd = 56
        dividerInsetStart = 56
    }
```

and assign to recycler view,

```
sampleRv.addItemDecoration(itemDecorator)
```

Inside apply scope, you can customize the things that are particular to divider such as insets, color etc.