# Why DividerItemDecoration get a null object reference in recyclerView fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

So i try to show my data from local database in recyclerView in HomeFragment, but when I start my app this getting error like this : Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.addItemDecoration(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$ItemDecoration)' on a null object reference
at org.d3ifcool.tasksreminder.ui.home.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.kt:50)

[this is my AddTaskAdapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbR2n.png)

[AddTaskViewModel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2cIr.png)

[HomeFragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVrlN.png)

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57886100/how-to-add-item-divider-for-recyclerview-in-kotlin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `recyclerView` object is `null`. Since you have implemented binding you should use your binding object. Also, move your code to `onViewCreated(View, Bundle?)` as you will want your view to have been created when you reference a view object

```kotlin
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    
    ...
    binding.recyclerView.addItemDecoration(...)
}
```